# Program to check whether a number can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers

Tags: c, primes

I wrote the following program to check whether a given number can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers. It compiles fine but does not work as expected. For eg, for input = 16, it displays that 16 cannot be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers. Also for eg, input = 5, it displays 5 = 3 + 2 rather than 5 = 2 + 3.

```
/* Program to check whether a number can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int x)
{
    int fact=0,i;
    for(i=2;i<x;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        {
            fact++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fact==0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,count=0;
    printf("Enter Number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(b=2;b<(a+1)/2;b++);
    {
        c = prime(b);
        d = prime(a-b);
        if (c==1 && d==1)
        {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n",a,b,a-b);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        {
            printf("%d cannot be expressed as sum of two prime numbers.\n",a);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So your program has some bad logic. In order to fix it, first *describe* it.

Comment: BTW, your `prime` is very suboptimal. Why do you keep looping after a first factor is found?

Comment: I am actually very new to programming. Any suggestions on how to optimise the function and/or improve the code ?

Comment: Why is `a` a `float`? I think that `int` may be a better choice

Comment: You can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to create a list of primes.

Comment: Is it better now ? And can anyone please tell me why is it at least not working as expected.

Comment: The first step is to write a good code to find prime numbers efficiently, before going further. The sieve is one method. With yours, if you store the primes in an array, those are the only trial divisors you will need up the the square root of the candidate . . . preferably the limit is the square of the supposed prime which should be <= candidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

In your function `prime()` you don't check `x` for the value of `2`, which would also be a prime number.

The second mistake is the `;` after the `for` statement.

```
for(b=2;b<(a+1)/2;b++);
```

Remove it, otherwise the following block (the part between `{` and `}`) is not executed for every loop iteration but only after the loop ended.

In general you don't want to read a float, you want an integer.  Use `fgets()` and `atoi()` for your use case.  These are much safer than `scanf()`.

As a last point: Add spaces before and after operators.  This makes the code much more readable.

### full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int x)
{
    int i;

    if (x == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 2; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int read_number;
    int summand1;
    int summand2;
    int count = 0;
    int max;
    char buffer[100];

    printf("Enter Number\n");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    read_number = atoi(buffer);

    max = (read_number + 1) / 2;

    for (summand1 = 2; summand1 < max; ++summand1)
    {
        summand2 = read_number - summand1;
        if ((prime(summand1) == 1) && (prime(summand2) == 1))
        {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n", read_number, summand1, summand2);
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("%d cannot be expressed as sum of two prime numbers.\n", read_number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you could do some optimizations.  For example in `prime()`:  If you already checked, that `x` is not a multiple of `2`, you can start your loop with `3` and increase `i` by `2` in very iteration.  Or you could stop this loop if `i` is greater than the square root of `x`.  These measures might speed up your code for large numbers, but it could make the code less readable.  That's a trade off you have to think about, especially if you are starting to learn programming.

Comment: Good spot on the `;` after the `for` statement, but bad advice on the limit, which only needs to be the square root of `x`. All prime numbers are odd, so `2` is an exception which can be discounted in any algorithm.

Comment: For i=2, it won't enter the `for(i=2;i<x;i++)` loop and thus fact would still remain 0 and the function would return 1. Isn't it ?

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, but it has to be checked if x is 2.

Comment: @HeLLo yes, but only once. the trade-off is checking every even divisor, which is far more expensive!

Comment: @AASingh what is the problem, isn't `2` a prime?

Comment: That is what I am saying. It counts 2 as a prime number and thus that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected code:

```
/* Program to check whether a number can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int x)
{
    int fact=0,i;
    if(x < 2) return 0;
    for(i=2;i<x;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        {
            fact++;
        }
    }
    if (fact==0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b,c,d,count=0;
    printf("Enter Number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(b=2;b<(a+1)/2;b++)//;mistake here!!
    {
        c = prime(b);
        d = prime(a-b);
        if (c==1 && d==1)
        {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n",a,b,a-b);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        {
            printf("%d cannot be expressed as sum of two prime numbers.\n",a);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The main issue was that you were ending the loop with semi column `;`. The other suggestion is to use `int` type everywhere.

Comment: Such a naive mistake. Any other way to optimise the code more ?

Comment: Yes, when you check for prime you need to check only until <= `sqrt(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the others have caught your bugs, but since you asked for an optimized version, here is a version that will go a bit faster.

The `prime` function only goes to `sqrt(x)` and only looks at odd values in the main loop. Also, in `main`, the loop only looks at odd values.

```
/* Program to check whether a number can be expressed as a sum of two prime
numbers*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
prime(int x)
{
    int pflg = 1;
    int sqr;
    int i;

    // 2,3 are prime
    if (x <= 3)
        return (x >= 2);

    // even numbers are not
    if ((x & 1) == 0)
        return 0;

    // get sqrt(x)
    for (sqr = 0;  (sqr * sqr) < x;  ++sqr);

    // we only need to check odd numbers
    for (i = 3; i <= sqr; i += 2) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            pflg = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return pflg;
}

int
main()
{
    int a,
     b,
     a2,
     count = 0;

    printf("Enter Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    a2 = (a + 1) / 2;

    // check when b is 2
    b = 2;
    if (b < a2) {
        // NOTE: if prime(b) is 0, no need to calculate prime(a - b)
        if (prime(b) && prime(a - b)) {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n", a, b, a - b);
            count++;
        }
    }

    // only odd b values can be prime
    for (b = 3; b < a2; b += 2) {
        // NOTE: if prime(b) is 0, no need to calculate prime(a - b)
        if (! prime(b))
            continue;
        if (! prime(a - b))
            continue;
        printf("%d = %d + %d\n", a, b, a - b);
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        printf("%d cannot be expressed as sum of two prime numbers.\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in `main`, the `if (prime(b) && prime(a - b)` uses what is called "short circuit evaluation". This means that if `prime(b)` returns 0, `prime(a - b)` will *not* be called/evaluated because `0 && whatever` can *never* be non-zero

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this simple code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check_Prime(int s)
{
    int flag = 0;
    for (int k = 2; k < s; k++)
    {
        if (s % k == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1, j = n - 1; i < n / 2, j >= n / 2; i++, j--) {
        int a = check_Prime(i);
        int b = check_Prime(j);
        if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n", n, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Consider if the input is 34,the variable i takes values from 1 to 34/2=17 and j takes values from 34-1=33 to 17.

So the corresponding sum i+j becomes

1+33, increment i by 1 and decrement j by 1

2+32

3+31......

Now check whether the corresponding i and j are prime by function check_Prime and display if it is.